# Are all public-key encryption protocols based on one-way functions?

Tags: public-key, one-way-function, trapdoor

Are there any public-key cryptography protocols which don't rely on one-way (or trapdoor) functions?

RSA and Diffie-Hellman cryptographic protocols both rely on one-way functions (prime factorization and discrete logarithm). Lattice-based cryptography is based on the Shortest Vector Problem which is NP-hard, but is it a one-way function?

Comment: Does this answer to your question [What primitives are needed to generically implement public-key cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42633/18298)

Comment: Note that you can always construct OWFs out of PKE but OWFs are (likely) not sufficient for PKE.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all public-key cryptography based on one-way functions. Every one-way function builds on some hard problem. There is many one-way functions in lattice-based crypto, that based on SVP. For example, NTRU one-way function, LWE one-way function, etc.

Comment: "Yes, all public-key cryptography based on one-way functions." That statement can be misinterpreted. Public-key cryptography is based on more than one-way functions.